# DropDownList DataTextField on Navigation property

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, navigation-properties, datatextfield

i need some help with the following.

i get a list of objects from the Entity Framework data context.

```
var list = context.EntityA;
```

the EntityA is the main object (contains the primary key), but has a navigation property called "EntityALanguages", which contains language specific properties.

now i want to bind the list to a dropdownlist and need so set DataValueField and DataTextField properties from the dropdownlist.

how can i set the DataTextField to a property of a navigation property, something like:

```
this.ddl.DataValueField = "GUID";
this.ddl.DataTextField = "EntityALanguages.ShortDescription";
```

> Edit:
>   The navigation property "EntityALanguages" is a collection, so EntityA -> EntityALanguages is a 1-n relation

Answer (score 0):

By using `var list = context.EntityA;` your navigation properties will be lazy loaded. Try `var list = context.EntityA.Include("EntityALanguages");` so your navigation propery will be present.

Comment: no that didn't do it. navigation properties are loaded correctly.

Comment: DataBinding: EntityA does not contain a property with the name 'EntityALanguages.ShortDescription'

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList may not support propertytrees for binding.

What you could do if you want to bind is to do the following:

var items = context.Entity.Include("EntityALanguages").Select(row => new { Id = row.GUID, Name = row.EntityALanguages.ShortDescription}).ToList();

ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
  ddl.DataValueField = "Id";

Answer (score 0):

In your entity EntityALanguages you could add a readonly property like this

```
public readonly string EntityALanguagesShortDescription
{
    get { return this.EntityALanguages.ShortDescription; }
}
```